# can boost vf2 deal with muti-graph like this situation?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I want to use vf2 in this situation.

```
Graph gsmall,glarge;
add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'),gsmall);
add_vertex(vertex_prop('b'),gsmall);
add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('m'), gsmall);

add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'),glarge);
add_vertex(vertex_prop('b'),glarge);
add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('m'), glarge);
add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('n'), glarge);
std::cout << is_subgraph_isomorphic(gsmall,glarge) << std::endl;
```

If the pattern's property of edge can match with graph's part of properties of edge, then return true, but now it must match all. That example returns false. I want to make it true, so how?

**Edit:**

I solved this question. Use vector and overload operator "=="

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6307210b2861bc63

But I found another problem. It will give wrong results when there is self-loops in graph.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46d336ecfddbbab9 is true

but http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/413d56146ceffd42 is false.

I think they are both ture. I can't understand how it could be like this.

Please help me again! Thanks!

Comment: AFAICT there is no function `is_subgraph_isomorphic` in boost. Where is it from? Do you have self-contained code? (This is what I got http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

Comment: So, this might be a good repro: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f67905bd8fceab10 vs. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a926998f94c8a0e ?

Comment: I updated my question and there is something wrong in self-loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost can deal with it. However, you're not looking for a isomorphism in the sense of the library:

> An isomorphism between two graphs G1=(V1, E1) and G2=(V2, E2) is a bijective mapping M of the vertices of one graph to vertices of the other graph that preserves the edge structure of the graphs

So, for all corresponding vertices, the same edges need to be present. In other words, the subgraph may be smaller (lower order) but each vertex must have equivalent structure (this implies the same number of edges).

In your case the small graph is structurally different because the large graph has a self loop, but the small doesn't. (The self loop is significant because both vertices exist in the subgraph).

If you really think for your purpose you need to ignore self loops, you'll have to filter them out.

Here's an example that employs the `filtered_graph` adaptor to achieve that:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e9b0e755ac4f09a)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/small_vector.hpp>

template <typename  SortedRange1, typename  SortedRange2,
    typename V = std::common_type_t<typename boost::range_value<SortedRange1>::type, typename boost::range_value<SortedRange2>::type>,
    typename Cmp = std::less<V> >
static inline bool has_intersection(SortedRange1 const& a, SortedRange2 const& b, Cmp cmp = {}) {
    auto equivalent = [cmp](V const& a, V const& b) 
        { return !cmp(a,b) && !cmp(b,a); };

    auto ai = a.begin();
    auto bi = b.begin();

    while (ai != a.end() && (bi = b.lower_bound(*ai)) != b.end())
        if (equivalent(*ai++, *bi))
            return true;

    return false;
}

// Define graph type
using Label = char; 

struct  EdgeProperties {
    using Labels = boost::container::flat_set<char, std::less<>, boost::container::small_vector<char, 3> >;

    EdgeProperties(std::initializer_list<Label> elabels = {}) :_elabels(elabels) {}

    bool operator==(EdgeProperties const& other) const {
        return has_intersection(_elabels, other._elabels);
    }

    Labels _elabels;
};

typedef boost::property<boost::edge_name_t, EdgeProperties> edge_prop;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, long/*, boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>*/ > vertex_prop;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, vertex_prop, edge_prop> Graph;


int main()
{
    Graph gsmall, glarge;
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'),gsmall);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('b'),gsmall);
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop({'m'}), gsmall);
    //add_edge(0, 0, edge_prop({'n'}), gsmall);

    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'),glarge);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('b'),glarge);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('c'),glarge);
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop({'m'}), glarge);
    add_edge(0, 0, edge_prop({'n'}), glarge);
    add_edge(0, 2, edge_prop({'o'}), glarge);

    // Create predicate of edge
    auto edge_comp = make_property_map_equivalent(
            get(boost::edge_name, gsmall),
            get(boost::edge_name, glarge));

    // Create callback
    boost::vf2_print_callback<Graph, Graph> callback(gsmall, glarge);

    struct FilterSelfEdges {
        Graph const* _g;
        bool operator()(Graph::edge_descriptor ed) const {
            return source(ed, *_g) != target(ed, *_g);
        }
    };

    using Filtered = boost::filtered_graph<Graph, FilterSelfEdges>;

    // Execute
    const bool result = boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(
            gsmall, Filtered(glarge, FilterSelfEdges{&glarge}), callback, boost::vertex_order_by_mult(gsmall),
            boost::edges_equivalent(edge_comp));

    std::cout << "subgraph isomorphic? " << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
(0, 0) (1, 1) 
subgraph isomorphic? true
```

Comment: Excellent! I found I misunderstood the concept of isomorphism, but I really need to match this situation in my project. Your answer exactly solves it.